# How to properly polyfill URLSearchParams in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, polyfills, isomorphic-fetch-api

I have a project that uses fetch polyfill from `isomorphic-fetch`. I would like to use URLSearchParams with it to submit POST data. For fetch to support URLSearchParams it first checks if it is available in global object. I though to use [this](https://github.com/WebReflection/url-search-params) polyfill for it but I don't know how to properly import it in webpack, so that `fetch` notices that it is available.

How can I accomplish this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had the same issue, had to switch to other polyfill to make it work, try this:

https://github.com/jerrybendy/url-search-params-polyfill

then simply add it to your webpack config:

```
entry: {
  bundle: [
    ...
    'url-search-params-polyfill',
    './src/entry'
  ]
}
```

Comment: There's also a more popular polyfill: https://github.com/WebReflection/url-search-params

Comment: @DmitriiSorin that's the exact same one linked in the question

Comment: right you are. I added a response to original answer below.

Comment: @DmitriiSorin WebReflections polyfill is deprecated. 
`This polyfill has been improved, better tested, and moved under the ungap umbrella. `
[@ungap/url-search-params.](https://github.com/ungap/url-search-params)

Comment: or import 'core-js/stable/url-search-params';

Answer (score -1):

How to include the `WebReflection/url-search-params` polyfill into webpack bundle:

```
entry: [
  'url-search-params/build/url-search-params.max',
  ...otherPolyfills,
  './your.entrypoint.jsx',
],
```

Comment: This one is deprecated, it mentions to use https://github.com/ungap/url-search-params instead.